# How can I read the previous edition of a book on iBooks?

Tags: macos, books

I accidentally updated my "The Swift Programming Language" book to the Swift 4 edition from Swift 3.1. Can I revert back to 3.1?

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes. It's not actually a "revert" back to the Swift 3.1 ebook. You simply just re-download it side by side the Swift 4 book, as I have done. Just open your Books app and search for the title, and if it's still available it'll show up.[image: image shows that I have several versions of the same book]

Answer (score 0):

If you use Time Machine and iCloud for your iBooks you could look here:

> ~/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents/

The path is only accessible via Terminal, so type in Terminal.App:

> open ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud\~com\~apple\~iBooks/Documents

This will open a Finder window with all your iBooks in it. Use this window to start Time Machine.

Please note: **I’m not sure if that folder is part of a default backup.**